# Plotting a double y axis when x and y lenghts differ

Tags: r, plot

I have two large data sets that I read into R. For simplicity, consider the following:

```
##Data set 1
x = c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010")
y = c(1,2,4,6,4,3)

##Data set 2
##Shorter than D2. Missing 2005
x1 = c( "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010")
y1 = c(20,40,60,50,29)
```

I want to plot both datasets as line plots with a double y axis. Ideally plotting would like this:

```
plot(x, y, type = "o", col = "red")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, y1, type = "o", col = "blue", 
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(4)
```

But of course the `x` any `y1` are not the same size so I get an error. I've tried

```
plot(x1, y1, type = "o", col = "blue", 
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

but then `y1` just gets stretch out to cover the entire length of.

In this simple case I could just add a blank row of `Y1` to cover the missing 2005 data, but it's not a practical solution in my real data. Is there anyway I can tell R to line up the two datasets accordingly?

Additionally, I would prefer to use gplots because I love the easy ability to offset my error bars. The code might look something like this

```
SE = c(.20,.40,.60,.50,.29)
SE1 = c(.20,.40,.60,.50,.29)
offset = .08

plotCI(x = x, y = y, uiw = SE, type = "o",col = "red")
par(new = TRUE)
plotCI(x = (x1) + offset, y = y1, type = "o", uiw = SE1, col = "blue",         
       xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(4)
```

Comment: A sample graphic would be handy. Do you want the values to scale through the height of the graph maybe just differentiated by colour (matching the axis)?  Or, do you want the scale to be the range of all of the values with the low ones very far down and the higher ones farther up?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm a new user so I could not post a pic of what I am hoping to do. But check out http://all-geo.org/highlyallochthonous/2007/09/how-fast-is-the-arctic-melting/. They have a double y axis plot similar to what I was hoping to create. Except in my case one of my plot lines has fewer years worth of data than the other.

Comment: I'd still be happy to hear what others have to say, but someone else shared the idea of using xlim=range(Data1$Year,Data2$Year) in the second plot command and this seems to fix it very well. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: I rolled back your (massive) edit, since you essentially created an entirely new question. This is disruptive since it creates a massive disconnect between the question and any existing answers. I recommend leaving this question as is and posting your edits as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd still be happy to hear what others have to say, but someone else shared the idea of using

```
xlim=range(Data1$Year,Data2$Year)
```

in the second plot command and this seems to fix it very well. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 1):

OK, you can do that if you have a mathematical relationship between your two ranges of values. Once you know what that is then you can do the plot.  But keep in mind, in the ice-sheets plot you refer to both of those axes refer to the exact same kind of data.  In fact, it's not really very helpful to be using those two axes... there should probably just be one.  They're obfuscating the difference between March and Sept. ice amounts.  You would need a really good justification to do what you're planning.

Maybe you have a good justification for this (although I can't think of any).  If you don't, it's a terrible idea.  This is how you would do it...

```
plot(x, y*10, type = 'l', ylim = range(c(y*10,y1)), yaxt = 'n', col = 'red')
axis(2, (1:6)*10, 1:6, col = 'red')
lines(x1, y1, col = 'blue')
axis(4, (1:6)*10, col = 'blue')
grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL)
```

You could set col.axis to set the colours of the numbers.

(The ice sheet example you show probably does the same thing as this.. subtracting 8 instead of multiplying by 10.)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. The ice sheet link was just to show an example of the type of plot I was hoping to create. My only reason for wanting to plot this kind of data is that I think I have a relationship between the two factors (y and y1), but their individual scales of magnitude are quite different. Again, thanks!

Comment: @VincentMoriarty, if you feel John answered your question, check the gray tick at the left side (just below the answer score) as the correct answer. This will make the question "solved".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `points()` to add points or lines to an existing plot:

```
plot(x,y,type="o",col="red")
points(x1,y1,type="o",col="blue")
```

Then you just need to add on the second axis.

Comment: Have you tried out your solution? (The blue points all fall outside of the plotting region).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Is there something similar for gplots? I like to use plotCI as it is easy to offset my error bars so they don't overlap.

Comment: @Josh - didn't notice that the second set of data is on a much larger scale. I thought of that over dinner, and assumed one of the resident R gurus would have posted a better solution. Maybe it's on its way?